# Java Equivalent of GetValue(int x)?

Tags: java, c#

I have to convert a c# program into Java and was hoping there was a Java equivalent to this statement. 
`string name= args.GetValue(i).toString();`

In c# it is being used as such:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
            {
                string name= args.GetValue(i).ToString();
                switch (name.ToUpper())
                ...
```

Comment: What type of Object is args? You're going to have to give us a bit more before we can do anything with it. Even C# is fine.

Comment: What's the type of `args`?

Comment: If this is a console app and args is the arguments being passed to the application you would access args like you would an array so args[i] if not then you would need to specify the type of args.

Comment: static void Main(string[] args)
{
      for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
                {
                    string name= args.GetValue(i).ToString();
...etc.

Comment: Then use args[i] with I being the index of the item that you are looking for.

Comment: Formal translation would be `args[i].toString()` though it's already a String so you could just do `args[i]`.

Comment: @CThompson, I've corrected the casing of `GetValue` in your question based on your comment.  There's a difference between `getValue` (which doesn't exist) and `GetValue`.  Try to be accurate when presenting code.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming args is the arguments passed to the program

```
public class test
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     String s0=args[0];
     String s1=args[1];
     System.out.println(s0+" "+s1);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

```
public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     //here you can access arguments by 
     String args0 = args[0];
     String args1 = args[1]; // and so on
     //then use parsing to turn it to any type you want
     int args0Int = Integer.parseInt(args0); // to int
     double args0Double = Double.parseDouble(args0); // to double

  }
}
```

You can send these arguments in terminal by changing the directory to the .class directory then type the following command

```
java CLASS_NAME args0 args1 .... argsN
```

As an Example

```
java Main 100
```